# Cannot compile new project targeting WinXP after installing VS2015 Update 3

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Steps to reproduce:
1. install vs2015 u3 RC
2. create a new win32 project
3. set Platform toolset to "Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)"
You can find the setting here:
Project -> Configuration properties -> General
4. Build

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory

(without step 3, it will compile just fine)

Answer (score 4):

This is [a known problem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs-knownissues/vs2015-update3-rc) with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 RC.

> **Visual C++ project build fails when using the v140_xp PlatformToolset**
>
> **Issue:**
>   When using PlatformToolset v140_xp, UCRT is not added to the Include
>   and Library path.
>
> **Workaround:**
>
> - In Visual Studio, go to the Solution Explorer.
> - Right click on the project, click on “Properties” Find and Select “VC++ Directories”
> - Append Includes Directory with “$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows
>     Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt”
> - Append Library Directory with “$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Windows
>     Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\$(PlatformShortName)”
> - Click OK or Apply to Save.